# Bcrypt Verify always returning false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
 [HttpPost("signUp")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> PostUserRegister(Users user)
    {
        if (userEmailExists(user.Email))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        string salt = BC.GenerateSalt(12);
        // hash password
        user.Password = BC.HashPassword(user.Password, salt);

        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.UserRegister @userName, @firstName, @lastName, @Password, @userEmail, @gender, @dob",
        new SqlParameter("@userName", user.UserName.ToString()),
        new SqlParameter("@firstName", user.FirstName.ToString()),
        new SqlParameter("@lastName", user.LastName.ToString()),
        new SqlParameter("@Password", user.Password.ToString()),
        new SqlParameter("@userEmail", user.Email.ToString()),
        new SqlParameter("@gender", user.Gender.ToString()),
        new SqlParameter("@dob", user.Dob));

       /* var format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(user.Dob, format);*/

        return Ok(user);
        //_context.Users.Add(users);
        //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //return CreatedAtAction("GetUsers", new { id = users.UserId }, users);
    }
```

Im siging a new user up like this. Hashing the password using Bcrypt.

```
using BC = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt;

[HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> PostUserLogin(Users user)
    {
        // get account from database
        var account = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == user.Email);

        // check account found and verify password
        if (account == null || !BC.Verify(user.Password, account.Password))
        {
            // authentication failed
            return Unauthorized(user);
        }
        else
        {
            // authentication successful
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Then I try to verify the password in the login function. When i debug to see the values of user.Password and account.Password they are correct. the user.Password is equal to the password the user entered to register and the account.Password is the Hashed password stored in the database. I was trying to follow this tutorial [ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Hash and Verify Passwords with BCrypt](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/16/aspnet-core-3-hash-and-verify-passwords-with-bcrypt)

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem with bCrypt like you.

The main problem was much simpler than I thought. The main reason for this was that I used **uppercase** and **lowercase** letters when I received and saved the password.

I Fixed this problem with make my password input to lower and save it to db
And When i want to verify it , i make the password lowercase again .

```
        user.Password = BC.HashPassword(user.Password.ToLower(), salt);
```

and when you want to **Verify** , use it like this:

```
  if (account == null || !BC.Verify(user.Password.ToLower(),account.Password))
```

I Think This is your question Answer.

Comment: It sounds like a bug, I just tested numbers. If the case in insensitive, it will have risk right?

Comment: Yes your Right i think its bug , but i dont think it is the risk @JasonPan

Answer (score 0):

I have read the blog you provided. And I think we should double check below points.

1. The format of Password in your db,if the orginal password is `11`, then the value stored should like :

   ```
   $2a$12$NTuJLk9/xZnlxP.oFj1mu.1ZypqYP4YuS1QbTBy7ofJwzKLSEEVBq
   ```
2. In this line `BC.Verify(user.Password, account.Password)`,

   The value of user.Password

   ```
   user.Password == 11
   ```

   And the value of account.Password

   ```
   account.Password == $2a$12$NTuJLk9/xZnlxP.oFj1mu.1ZypqYP4YuS1QbTBy7ofJwzKLSEEVBq
   ```

Please double check it, if you still have some issue,  you can add the picture with debugging result.

Comment: when you use this: BC.Verify(user.Password, account.Password) , Bcrypt encrypts and compares itself automatically (its encrypt the user.Password)